# Array that copies its contents to another array backwards is not working properly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

When I run through this code it is my understanding that `arrayA` will be copied to `arrayB` backwards. So when I try to view what's in `arrayB[1]`, it should be 6, but it's coming out to 0.

I know this code is inefficient. This is only an exercise to use the operators `offset`, `sizeof` and `lengthof` to avoid direct memory access and any use of constants. I'm a student, so the simplest fix is the best fix.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall ; memory system

.stack 4096 ; declare stack memory size 4kb
  ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data

  arrayA word 01d, 05d, 06d, 02d
  arrayB word 00d, 00d, 00d, 00d

.code
  main proc
    mov eax, 0
    mov esi, offset arrayA
    mov ecx, sizeof arrayA
    mov ebx, lengthof arrayB
    sub ebx, 1

    L1:
        mov ax, [esi]
        add esi, type arrayA
        mov arrayB[ebx], ax
        sub ebx, 1
        sub ecx, type arrayA
        cmp ecx, 0
        jne L1

    mov ax, arrayB[1]

    invoke ExitProcess,0
  main endp
end main
```

Comment: Looks like code not properly adapted to `arrayB` being `word`. Need to change `sub ebx, 1` to `sub ebx, type arrayB` and `mov ax, arrayB[1]` to `mov ax, arrayB[type ArrayB]` (with `type arrayB` being `2` for `word`).

Comment: ok I tried that but it didn't work, wouldn't you need to subtract 1 initially from ebx so it gets the 4th value (index 3) at the start of the loop, and do it once per loop? Since I stored length of arrayB into ebx at the beginning which is 4.

Comment: You have words. Each is 2 bytes. You have to do the same thing you did for `arrayA`, namely scale everything by `2` aka. `typeof arrayB`. Edit: I see you used `lengthof` which gives item count not byte size, so you should also change that.

Comment: ok, thanks it works, but why does `mov ax, arrayB[1]` not return 6 but `mov ax, arrayB[type ArrayB]` does? and how do I represent other indexes of `arrayB` like `mov ax, arrayB[0]` or `mov ax, arrayB[2]`

Comment: You need to scale everything by 2 because each word is 2 bytes. Addressing works on bytes. As such `arrayB[1]` returns the top half of the first item combined with the low half of the second item.

Comment: ok, I got it so since a word is 16bits you go up by 2bytes like `arrayB[2]` or `arrayB[6]`, but how do you represent the first position? `arrayB[0]` is not working.

Comment: That should work.

Comment: you're right, made an error, thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207443/discussion-between-william-mayberry-and-jester).